# Web site development with Hugo Tikva theme and Bootstrap-4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, hugo

I'm completely revising my company web site using the Hugo framework and Bootstrap. Developing web sites is not my business so I need help understanding how to use a Hugo theme (Tikva) and Bootstrap to get the site to appear as I want it to. I've used only html and css on my site since I first developed it in 1993. Now I need to add modern features such as screen size adaption, a blog, and site search capability.

I have all my revised page content, images, and menu created. My immediate problem is learning why, with the Bootstrap quick start installed, the site (locally loaded with 'hugo server') doesn't display the menu and and pages properly,

Where do I earn whether I need to focus on the Hugo theme or Bootstrap?

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic, as it's not a programming question, as written. Also, you haven't shown any specific issue, whether CSS or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I took the same approach with the web site as I do with a Python, R, or SQL program by reducing it to only the index page and working through the config.toml. Progress has been made and will continue.

Comment: Ok that's great but... this isn't an answer.